# Cross-matching two 2D arrays and returning the indexes of the matches

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I have two arrays, `A` and `B`, of shape `(m, 2)` and `(n, 2)`, respectively, with `n >> m`. In my case, `n = 8013` and `m = 71`. Each row `(x, y)` of each array represents the coordinates of a point source in an astronomical image, in pixel units. All the rows in the `A` have very close values to some of the rows of `B`, but not exactly the same. In some cases, the difference is some decimals, in others, maybe one or two integers, e.g. one row in `A` is `(1158, 1304.8974)` and its corresponding row in B is `(1160, 1304.6578)`.

My question is: how to find the indices of the elements in `B` that are the closest ones to the elements in `A`?

My first attempt is:

```
matched = []
indexes = []
for k in np.arange(0, len(A)):
    idx = np.where((B[:, 0].astype(int) == A[k, 0].astype(int)) & 
                   (B[:, 1].astype(int) == A[k, 1].astype(int)))
    matched.append(B[idx])
    indexes.append(idx)
```

But it is only returning the indices of rows in `A` whose integers are exactly the same as the elements in `B`, and therefore does not match all the items. If I remove the `astype(int)`, I have even fewer matches.

A second attempt I've tried, for a single row, is:

```
value = A[0]
X = np.abs(B - value)
idx = np.where(X == X.min())
B[idx[0]]
```

But it only calculates the closest value of either `x` or `y` columns, not both. This means that if I have one row in `A` that I want to match, such as `(1230, 980)`, and two rows in `B`, such as `(3450, 981)` and `(1233, 975)`, the latter being the correct match and expected output, this second implementation returns the element `(3450, 981)` as the correct match to `(1230, 980)`, as the point `y = 980` is closer to `y = 981` than to `y = 975`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for distance in the most conventional form: Euclidean.

Since your numbers are ~10k by ~100, computing the distances between all of them will not be especially expensive in terms of time or memory on any reasonably modern hardware. If it were expensive, I would recommend something like [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), which effectively implements proper spatial sorting.

The simplest way to get the distances between each set of points is using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). This is not always as fast as computing the distance "by hand", but it will be fast enough:

```
dist = cdist(A, B)
```

`dist` is a `(m, n)` array. You can find the indices of the minimal distance in each row using [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
idx = np.argmin(dist, axis=1)
```

The corresponding elements of `B` are

```
matches = B[idx, :]
```

This assumes that your input arrays `A` and `B` are numpy arrays to begin with. If that is not the case, start by making them into arrays:

```
A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
```

If you wanted to implement the distance "manually", which would be faster, you could use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to compute the square root of the sums of squared differences:

```
dist = np.sqrt(sum((A.reshape(-1, 1, 2) - B.reshape(1, -1, 2))**2, axis=-1))
```

The final square root is not necessary if you just want to find the minima, since square root increases monotonically, and the minimum of the squared distance occurs at the minimum distance.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the case of your idx definition to an acceptable range like this:

```
idx = np.where((B[:, 0].astype(int) >= A[k, 0].astype(int) - 3) & (B[:, 0].astype(int) <= a(k,0].astype(int + 3)) & (B[:, 1].astype(int) == A[k, 1].astype(int)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I've tried it and one of the problems is that, in the case I put a tolerance of e.g. 3, as suggested, sometimes more than one index is returned, as I'm working in a catalog with a crowded field.